# How do I run this GitHub java project?

Tags: java, github, classpath

I want to run this GitHub java program:
https://github.com/ss2cp/AI-TicketToRide

According to the README.md it should run with `src/ttr.main/TTRMain`

I am trying to start the game in **linux**, but I keep on getting the error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class src.ttr.main.TTRMain
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: src.ttr.main.TTRMain

I tried

```
java src.ttr.main.TTRMain
java src/ttr.main/TTRMain
src/ttr.main/TTRMain
java ttr.main.TTRMain
java -jar JGame.jar
java -cp . src.ttr.main.TTRMain
java -cp . ttr.main.TTRMain
```

from the `~/Downloads/AI-TicketToRide-master/` folder (where the README.md and .classpath file is).
I also tried it from `~/Downloads/AI-TicketToRide-master/bin/ttr/main/` and `~/Downloads/AI-TicketToRide-master/src/ttr/main/`

But no luck.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and openjdk 11.0.20.1 2023-08-24.

How do I start the program and from which directory? And should I set a classpath?

Comment: The edu.virginia.engine imports make it seem like you need some libraries from the University of Virginia to run this program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following sequence of commands works for me.

1. Clone the repository:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/ss2cp/AI-TicketToRide.git
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** Requires [Git](https://git-scm.com/) to be installed on your computer.</sup>
2. Navigate to the project directory:

   ```
   cd AI-TicketToRide
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** This is necessary, as the image files in the project's `resources` directory are loaded as files relative to the working directory.</sup>
3. Execute the project:

   ```
   java -cp bin:lib/JGame.jar ttr.main.TTRMain
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** Requires Java 8+ to be on your path.</sup>

   <sup>**Note:** On Windows, replace the `:` (colon) in the `-cp` argument with a `;` (semicolon). You can also replace the `/` (forward slash) with a `\` (backslash), but that is not strictly necessary (Java will correctly interpret the value either way).</sup>

#### Class-path

The `-cp bin:lib/JGame.jar` part is specifying the class-path. In this case, two locations are being put on the class-path. The `bin` directory contains the compiled class files of the source files in the `src` directory. The `lib/JGame.jar` file contains precompiled third-party code used by the project.

Normally, I would say the `resources` directory should also be put on the class-path, but that does not seem to be necessary here. It appears those images, instead of being loaded as *resources* like the directory name would imply, are being loaded as *files*. Luckily, *relative* file paths seem to be used, but this means that the project directory **must** be the working directory.

#### Main class

The `ttr.main.TTRMain` part is the fully qualified [binary name](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getName()) of the main class. Note the `src` directory is a "source root"; it is not part of the package structure.

The class-path will be searched for the specified main class and, if found, execute that class's main method. Since the `bin` directory, which contains the `ttr/main/TTRMain.class` file, has been put on the class-path, the `ttr.main.TTRMain` class will be found.

Answer (score 1):

The class is in the `ttr.main` package, and named `TTRMain`. Further, there is a `bin` folder containing the **compiled** classes. So, the command you want is to specify the `bin` folder on your classpath and then the fully qualified class name. Like,

```
java -cp bin ttr.main.TTRMain
```

Answer (score 0):

To run a Java program, you need to specific the classpath to all the .jar, .class, and resources it needed.  You could run the program as below:

`java -cp ./lib/;./bin;./imgs;/resources ttr.main.TTRMain`

If you plan to run it often, you want to create a .bat or .sh file and put that line in it so you can execute the script each time you want to run the program.